# How to have warning when casting `int_least8_t` to `char`?

Tags: c, casting, typedef

I am building a string library to support both ascii and utf8.
I create two typedef for `t_ascii` and `t_utf8`. ascii is safe to be read as utf8, but utf8 is not safe to be read as ascii.
Do I have any way to issue a warning when implicitely casting from `t_utf8` to `t_ascii`, but not when implicitely casting `t_ascii` to `t_utf8` ?

Ideally, I would want these warnings (and only these warnings) to be issued:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef char           t_ascii;
typedef uint_least8_t  t_utf8;

int main()
{
    t_ascii const* asciistr = "Hello world"; // Ok
    t_utf8 const*   utf8str = "你好世界";    // Ok

    asciistr = utf8str; // Warning: utf8 to ascii is not safe
    utf8str = asciistr; // Ok: ascii to utf8 is safe

    t_ascii asciichar = 'A';
    t_utf8   utf8char = 'B';

    asciichar = utf8char; // Warning: utf8 to ascii is not safe
    utf8char = asciichar; // Ok: ascii to utf8 is safe
}
```

Currently, when building with -Wall (and even with `-funsigned-char`), I get these warnings:

```
gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra                          
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:35: warning: pointer targets in initialization of ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const unsigned char *’} from ‘char *’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   10 |         t_utf8 const*   utf8str = "你好世界";    // Ok
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
main.c:12:18: warning: pointer targets in assignment from ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const unsigned char *’} to ‘const t_ascii *’ {aka ‘const char *’} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   12 |         asciistr = utf8str; // Warning: utf8 to ascii is not safe
      |                  ^
main.c:16:17: warning: pointer targets in assignment from ‘const t_ascii *’ {aka ‘const char *’} to ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const unsigned char *’} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   16 |         utf8str = asciistr; // Ok: ascii to utf8 is safe
      |                 ^
```

Comment: maybe `int_least8_t` is an alias for `char`?

Comment: I think you should wrap these into opaque structures, which will be distinct as far as the C type system goes, even if they both wrap the same underlying `char *`. Arguably (and C programmers will disagree with me, I know), what you haven't aren't string types, they're character pointers.

Comment: Actually, I am observing a warning: `warning: assigning to 'const t_ascii *' (aka 'const char *') from 'const t_utf8 *' (aka 'const signed char *')`. Note that plain `char` has "signness" that is neither signed and unsigned

Comment: Does you question *actually* ask about casting the native types, rather than (as in the examples you give) casting *pointers* to those types? Different things. Very different, really.

Comment: The only asymmetrical warning I'm aware of is conversion between objects of different sizes, e.g. assigning a `uint8_t` to a `uint16_t` **does not warn**, but assigning a `uint16_t` to a `uint8_t` **does warn**. That of course does not apply to pointers. Converting pointers to different sized types always requires an explicit cast. So I think the answer to your question is just, "No".

Comment: It's reasonable to assume the question is about casting pointers to those types, since that is the substance of the warning it is asking to suppress.  But, it's good that you pointed out those are distinct issues here, as OP's comment seems to not appreciate the substance of the warning. @user3386109 - what the warning is warning you about is casting the pointer - if you for example used it as an array or indirected an element, and it had the sign bit set, that might perform an unintended non-sign-extended conversion.  As I say in my answer, the warning is about the /signedness/, not the size.

Comment: @BadZen The warning is about the types being incompatible. The C type system is somewhat dysfunctional since it treats `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` as 3 different types, regardless of what signedness `char` happens to have. The type specifier rules is one of the more broken things in C... if C had sane type specifier rules we wouldn't be allowed to write `#define very signed signed signed` ... `very signed char ch;` and similar nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin - The types are not "incompatible" with regard to implicit casting.  You can implicitly cast between different signs.   The warning is specifically about pointers to types of different sign, as it says plainly, and these /are different types/ than the types they point to.  No implicit cast between the pointed-to types is actually performed in the listed code at that place.

Comment: There is nothing called "implicit casting" - there are implicit conversions and explicit conversions and a cast is always explicit, using the cast operator. Implicit conversions are only allowed during valid forms of assignment dealing with regular variables (arithmetic types). As I already quoted in another comment, assignment is more picky when it comes to pointer types - they must be compatible and may not remove qualifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `-Wall`. Always compile with `-Wall`.

```
<user>@squall:~/src/p1$ gcc -Wall -c test2.c
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:9:31: warning: pointer targets in initialization of ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const signed char *’} from ‘char *’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
    9 |     t_utf8  const*  utf8str = "你好世界";
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.c:11:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment from ‘const t_ascii *’ {aka ‘const char *’} to ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const signed char *’} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   11 |     utf8str = asciistr; // Ok: ascii to utf8 is safe
      |             ^
test2.c:12:14: warning: pointer targets in assignment from ‘const t_utf8 *’ {aka ‘const signed char *’} to ‘const t_ascii *’ {aka ‘const char *’} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   12 |     asciistr = utf8str; // Should issue warning: utf8 to ascii is not safe
      |              ^
```

You want it to be safe to cast from `t_ascii` from `t_utf8`, but it's simply not.   The signedness differs.

The warning is not about the fact that valid utf8 is sometimes not valid ASCII - the compiler knows nothing about that.   The warning is about the sign.

If you want an unsigned `char`, compile with `-funsigned-char`.  But then neither warning will be issued.

(By the way, if you think that type `int_least8_t` will be able to hold a multibyte char / complete utf8 codepoint encoding - it will not.   All `int_least8_t` and consequently `utf8_t` in a single compilation unit will have the exact same size.)

Comment: No matter if the `char` type is signed or unsigned under the hood, the first bit should always be 0 for valid ascii characters.  
How is casting from `t_ascii` (aka `char`) to `t_utf8` (aka `int_least8_t`) not safe ?  
How could one safely convert a `t_ascii` to a `t_utf8` ?

Comment: A conforming compiler is required to give a diagnostic message when assigning a pointer to another pointer and they aren't compatible types. No need for `-Wall` as such, just use a conforming compiler. gcc is not conforming by default settings, is all. clang appears to be conforming in this case even with default settings.

Comment: @Lundin - conforming to /what/?  Please cite the standard if you are making this claim.   (In particular, it's not the ANSI C standard, which states:  "An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, *none of which are specified as part
of this International Standard*. The following are a few of the more common situations...")   What standard details which compiler warnings should be issued by default?

Comment: Conforming to the the C standard ISO IEC 9899:2018, 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment - constraints. Specifically, this must hold true: "the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;".

Comment: That says nothing about what warnings the compiler must issue, and does not even apply to any of the assignment statements in this post.  I don't think you're understanding it, but this is way off-topic now.  Let's continue in a side conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compile it with a standard C compiler. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Result:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:9:31: error: pointer targets in initialization of 'const t_utf8 *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'} from 'char *' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
    9 |     t_utf8 const*   utf8str = "你好世界";    // Ok
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:14: error: pointer targets in assignment from 'const t_utf8 *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'} to 'const t_ascii *' {aka 'const char *'} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   11 |     asciistr = utf8str; // Warning: utf8 to ascii is not safe
      |              ^
<source>:12:13: error: pointer targets in assignment from 'const t_ascii *' {aka 'const char *'} to 'const t_utf8 *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'} differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   12 |     utf8str = asciistr; // Ok: ascii to utf8 is safe
      |             ^
```

---

> but not when implicitely casting t_ascii to t_utf8 ?

No you can't have that in standard C, since it's an invalid pointer conversion. You can silence the compiler with an explicit cast, but you are invoking undefined behavior if you do.

---

Apart from that, you could use C11 `_Generic` to find out which type `uint_least8_t` boils down to:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define what_type(obj) printf("%s is same as %s\n", #obj, \
  _Generic ((obj),                                        \
            char: "char",                                 \
            unsigned char: "unsigned char",               \
            signed char: "signed char") );
  

int main (void)
{
    typedef char           t_ascii;
    typedef uint_least8_t  t_utf8;

    t_ascii ascii;
    t_utf8  utf8;

    what_type(ascii);
    what_type(utf8);
}
```

Output on gcc x86 Linux:

```
ascii is same as char
utf8 is same as unsigned char
```